# How to make html page keep displaying rows of information from servlet (when user presses submit to enter new data items)

Tags: java, html, mysql

I have a table in SQL database with columns "Item Code", "Item Name", "Description", "Rate". I am using eclipse Java IDE. Using HTML page, I will create a table as you can see in the image (link above).

When the user presses "Submit" in the HTML page, it will insert it into the respective columns in the database by sending the info to a Java servlet. How can I make the HTML page keep displaying (row by row) new data entries as shown in the below image? (e.g. superannuation, expenses as shown in image. Basically, every time the user presses "Submit", I want the HTML page to keep adding new rows and displaying the data items from database.

[image]

Comment: Use jquery or javascript to manipulate the DOM, and jquery to to send Ajax to servlet to insert into DB

Answer (score 1):

So far as I understand your question :
it can be done in different ways, I will try to explain in two simple ways.

with javascript - client sided or
with java - server sided.

Basically each time your user press "Submit" you send the html form to the server, which will insert/update some new data to the database. Now you have to represent the data from database again.

with javascript + java :
each time your user press submit, you send an AJAX request to server. With AJAX you can send form data to server, after you send your form data to the server, you wait for the answer from the server.

So now your server has to add the data to the database, and if it's successfull.
Get all data from database, and respond to the client. 
Client has to fetch the data.

After you fetch the data, you have to change your html document with the new data.

with java:

if you use only java, you can just send your html form data with submit button.

when the server adds data to the database, you have to re write your html page, which now will contain all data from the database. I suggest JSP(Java Server Pages).

Differences between theese two approaches :

with javascript + java : you don't have to refresh your page after your user press submit button. You can even do some animations, while waiting for the data get back from the server.

with java(JSP) :  each time your user press submit button, you have to refresh the whole page : it's the old way.

with only java :

servlet :

```
if(request.getParameter("formData"))!=null) {
//databaseSaving logic;

}
   //now when it's saved, you have to get the all data, and add it to page scope, so JSP page can access to the data

request.setAttribute("dataName",data);
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp")
```

jsp :

```
//for example
//jstl and expression language
        <c:forEach items="${data}" var="dataName">
            <a href="details?id=${Zaposlenik.getId()}">   
            ${dataName.getId()}
            ${dataName.getName()}
            ${dataName.getAge()}
         </a>
            <br />
        </c:forEach>
```

or you can use scriptlets

```
<%
//write the same code as you have written in basic java classes.
%>
```

---

javascript + java :

javascript :

this is just basic ajax tutorial.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

java:

you can again combine servlets and jsp for this.

servlet :

is the same as above.

jsp :

```
<table>

</table>
```

you can put your javascript in jsp.

```
<script>
//when user press submit, send request
//after your server respons with data
//change with javascript the html in jsp
</script>
```

I hope I helped. Tried to explain the logic, not the code. You can allways google for some examples.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback, I want to use only servlet and jsp (i.e. user has to refresh page). I'll do some research and have a look as to how this can be done (I haven't used JSP before, only html).

Comment: @user6462496 you can use only servlets if you want, anyways you should research a bit :)

Comment: How can I use only servlets? :)

Comment: here example

http://pastebin.com/QnSSn2vX